# Can NumericArray be Compiled?

Tags: compile, numeric-array

I've have a big block of code written under `Compile`. Some other part of the code which receives data from `shared Q` useing `NumericArray`, need to be called inside the `Compile`.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
demoFile = FileNameJoin[{$CCompilerDirectory, "SystemFiles", "CSource", "mathNshmem.cpp"}];
lib = CreateLibrary[{demoFile}, "testDLL"];
datarcv = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "get_data", {{LibraryDataType[NumericArray], "Constant"}}, {LibraryDataType[NumericArray]}];
```

where `"get_data"` is a `C` code to receive data from `sharedQ`, this way,

```
numar = NumericArray[Range[12], "Real64"];
datarcv[numar]
```

[image]

I'm doing the analysis using codes written under `Compile`. So, `datarcv[numar]` needs to be called from under `Compile`. However `Compile` is unable to process the `NumericArray`. Below is a sample;

```
fn = Compile[{{arr, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{numarr},
    numarr = NumericArray[arr, "Real64"];
    Normal[numarr]
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```

```
In[273]:= 
arr = {0.053`, 0.002`, 0.`, 0.00345`, 0.035`, 0.0009`, 0.05`, 0.0026`};
NumericArray[arr, "Real64"];
Normal[%]
fn[arr]

Out[275]= {0.053, 0.002, 0., 0.00345, 0.035, 0.0009, 0.05, 0.0026}

During evaluation of In[273]:= CompiledFunction::cfte: Compiled expression NumericArray[Type: Real64
Dimensions: {8}

] should be a rank 1 tensor of machine-size real numbers.

During evaluation of In[273]:= CompiledFunction::cfexe: Could not complete external evaluation; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

Out[276]= {0.053, 0.002, 0., 0.00345, 0.035, 0.0009, 0.05, 0.0026}
```

Is there a way to bypass this problem? If I use `mathKernel` to first receive the data and then to proceed with the computation, it heavily slows down the computation speed as the computation needs to be done iteratively while the data is being received. I'm using `$Version = "12.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)"`.

Comment: `Compile` is the old way to compile functions in Mathematica. You probably want to check the new one, `FunctionCompile`, and this documentation page: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/compiledtype/NumericArray.html

Comment: @kirma; How may I update a global variable under ```FunctionCompile```? Like ```FunctionCompile[Function[{Typed[arg,"Real64"]},gblvar = fun[arg, gblvar]]]```, 'gblvar' is a global variable that needs to be updated . How parallelization/threading can be done under ```FunctionCompile```?

Comment: Frankly I haven't looked at that; I just know that both `NumericArray` and `FunctionCompile` are parts of new frameworks which are expected to co-operate; if I would have a full answer I would have written it as an answer, not a comment. :I